# Kronecker delta question!

Tags: tensors, kronecker-delta

I am trying to grasp the basics of tensor calculus.
I've come across the Kronecker delta and it confused me.
$$\delta_j^i=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&1, i=j\\
&0,i\not=j
\end{aligned}
\right.$$which is the same as $\delta_j^i=\delta_{ij}=\delta^{ij}$. I've seen also that $${\partial x^i\over\partial x^j}=\delta_j^i$$That got me thinking and i guess that $${\partial x^i\over\partial x^j}={\partial x_i\over\partial x_j}={\partial x^i\over\partial x_j}={\partial x_i\over\partial x^j}=\delta_j^i=\delta_{ij}=\delta^{ij}$$ is correct(all are equal to each other). Please , I'd like to know If I am correct and If not, please help me understand it.

Comment: This is just a matter of notation

Comment: The Kronecker delta are just the components of the unit matrix.

Comment: You can write whatever form of the Kronecker delta which is compatible with Einstein's summation convention, to preserve index balance.

Comment: I'd like to thank you all for your comments/answers. They helped me a lot and now it's more clear.